# This Series is Frustrating: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{1/n}-1}{n^{0.2}}$

Tags: calculus

> Does this series converge or diverge? $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{1/n}-1}{n^{0.2}}$$

I have founded an upper boundary for $n^{1/n}-1$ which happens to be $1$. I couldn't proceed any further. All the other convergence test didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$n^\frac1n =e^{\frac{\log n}n} \sim 1+\frac{\log n}n$$

then

$$\frac{n^{1/n}-1}{n^{0.2}} \sim \frac{\log n}{n^{1.2}}$$

then the given series converges by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n^{1.1}}$.

Comment: What are you using $\sim$ for?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I'm using that to indicate "asymptotically equivalent". To make the argument rigorous we need to refer to LCT.